# How to convert EntityCollection<T> to List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to convert an EntityCollection to a List but I don't see a way to do this.

Something like:

```
List<myEntity> entityList = myEntityCollection.ToList();
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Did you try:

```
 List<myEntity> entityList = new List<myEntity>(myEntityCollection);
```

And by the way if you import the `System.Linq` namespace in order to bring the [`.ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) extension method into scope, there's no reason why:

```
List<myEntity> entityList = myEntityCollection.ToList();
```

wouldn't work as [`EntityCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354106.aspx) implements `IEnumerable<T>`.